# Full-wave rectifier with pi-filter

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, rectifier, math, bridge-rectifier

For a project I'm working on, I've to calculate a function for the output voltage of this filter:

[image]

The things I calculate:

1. The input voltage:
   $$\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega t+\theta\right)$$
2. The voltage after the rectifier: $$\text{U}_{\text{C1}}\left(t\right)=\left|\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)\right|=\left|\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega t+\theta\right)\right|$$
3. Using Laplace transform, I got for the output voltage:
   $$\frac{\text{U}_{\text{C2}}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\mathcal{L}_t\left[\left|\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)\right|\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}}=\frac{1}{1+\text{L}\cdot\text{C}_2\cdot\text{s}^2}$$

Where \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$

---

> Questions: 1. Why does the output voltage not depend on the value of \$\text{C}_1\$? 2.Is the amplitude of the voltage after the (not ideal) rectifier equal to: \$\hat{\text{u}}-\text{V}_{\text{d}}\approx\hat{\text{u}}-0.7\$

Comment: A fullwave rectification has **two** diode losses.

Comment: @JImDearden So the amplitude drops with \$\text{V}_{\text{d}}\approx1.4\$?

Comment: only when current is flowing, yes (ish)

Comment: Depending upon how close you want to model the losses the voltage drop across the diodes will be a function of the current through the diodes. Google diode equation.

Comment: Equation 2 is not valid, the whole point of having a C1 is to fill in the valley of the absolute sine. There is no transfer function for a rectifier circuit, it is significantly non-linear.

Comment: @rioraxe, There is a TF for the LC network (which is what the OP actually has), and the output voltage can be determined using the LT of the rectified sine as input signal. The resultant LT is non-analytic, though!

Comment: @Chu How would you set up the equation for that "rectified sine as input signal"? It is most definitely not \$U_{C1} = |u \sin(wt) |\$.

Comment: @rioraxe Why does the voltage after the rectifier not look like my equation 2?

Comment: Because the function of a diode is very much non-linear and depends on the circuits around it. Go measure any rectifier circuit with a filter capacitor, you cannot find a signal of the form \$|u \sin(wt)|\$ anywhere.

Comment: @rioraxe Huh? That's what a full-wave rectifier does, it flips the negative part of the sine wave to the positive part and you get a signal that looks like equation 2?!

Comment: If it connects to nothing. But it is connected to something (the C-L-C) and that changes the signal and the dependency is non-linear. You asked why there is no dependency on C1, the reason is you have assumed the output from the diodes is a perfect variable voltage source while it is not.

Comment: A reasonable approximation to this is, ignore L and C2 initially. Assume a constant current draw from the rectifier and C1, work out the ripple voltage. Now apply L and C2 as a filter to the ripple voltage. The ripple voltage is going to take the classic rectifier output shape, approximate it as a sine wave is probably close enough for most cases.

Comment: @rioraxe What the OP has done is 'ignore' the diode bridge and come up with a tf for the system after rectification (at C1). You can do that because ideally at C1 you already have a DC source.  In fact, you could f'orget' you had an AC wave and just work with the DC signal. Now, if the OP wanted the transfer function for the whole circuit (from the AC source all the way to C2) that wouldn't work for the reasons you have stated, can't model non linear systems with Laplace transform unless you linearize around some operating point. And of course how good DC source depends on the current drawn.

Comment: @SixtoCabrera Is there a way to model it from the AC source to voltage across C2?

Comment: I don't know for sure how I'd approach something like that but it most definitely needs the use of linearization so that you could model the system using laplace transform. It seems to be complex.

Comment: This model is insufficient.  Without R values for each and every component including load, the results will be poor.  and with no load the LC values wont matter. it just charges to peak, û.   Due to the sag, the load RC value affects both the mean voltage and pp ripple.  It is nonlinear so the transform is wrong. The voltage drop on proper sized diodes may be 0.7 to 1V at full rating because diode surge current is inverse the load regulation , thus 10% ripple may be near 10x Iavg DC but only when On 10% of the time

Answer (score 1):

Your transfer function doesn't depend on \$C_1\$ because after the diode bridge, \$C_1\$ acts pretty much as a source. I would think of this circuit as a DC source at \$C_1\$ and an LC network to filter out the ripple.

Ideally, you could just consider \$C_1\$ as a DC voltage source (how good of a DC source depends on the its capacitance and how much current it is being drawn by the circuitry to the right of \$C_1\$). That's what you have in the denominator of your TF on the left hand side, you're using \$V_{c1}\$ as your input.

Even though you have a transfer function that includes \$L\$ and \$C_2\$, ideally, the DC portion coming from \$C_1\$ is unaffected. That means that not even the last LC filter changes the DC portion (ideal case). That is evident if you where to evaluate your TF at \$s=0\$, which is the case for a DC signal. Now, in reality, what's going to change your output voltage/current are the ESR losses associated with the capacitors and inductor of the filter. And of course, \$L\$ and \$C_2\$ will further smooth out your output signal.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But are my calculations true? Are they right or not? And what whould this circuit look like when it is not idealy?

Comment: @KlaasP Your transfer function is Ok and the output voltage is actually the the peak value of the sine wave minus two voltages drops of the diodes that are on during each half cycle. If you take into account ESR losses, then you'd have to add a series resistance to each of the elements, the inductor and the caps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way for an approximation and I will assume ideal components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2lhS1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image]

Start with an abbreviation circuit on the left, assume a constant current is drawn. Uc takes on the classic scalloped-shaped rippled voltage. This would be the first part of the approximation.

If we apply the same constant current approximation to the circuit on the right, then Uc would take on the form \$u |\sin(wt)|\$. But that is a bad approximation because if there is any filter element further down, the current becomes discontinuous when the diodes are off. To get the form \$u |\sin(wt)|\$, current must flow continuously through a pair of diodes, it can be true if the load is a resistor to ground, but this is not the case here.

This part of the circuit is clearly non-linear. Couple of indications are -- the diodes switching on and off; the fundamental frequency of the signal doubled.

Now go back to the scalloped-rippled voltage, one way is to represent that with a Fourier series. Assuming decent filtering, there will be a large DC component and smaller harmonics of \$2w\$. A reasonable approximation can be taking only the DC component and the first harmonic. Equate the DC to the average, and equate the amplitude of the first harmonic to the ripple. Now that can be passing through a LC filter and be processed linearly.

One of the earlier assumption is that the current coming off the rectifier with capacitor is constant. That assumption can be checked by comparing the inductor L current to the average current.

Let's say we try to get a transfer function end to end through some kind of  approximation, but no transfer function can produce the harmonics, including the dominant \$2w\$ component, from a pure \$w\$ source.